# How to get Remaining Time in Days Hours Minutes And seconds with Moment Library

Tags: momentjs

I want to get the remaining time in Days Hours Minutes And seconds (00:00:00:00)

I have a record which have

```
endDate=2014-07-17T00:00:00Z
```

How can I use moment to get the remaining time. Currently I have code which gives me wrong result

```
var endDate=new Date('2014-07-17T00:00:00Z');
var todayDate = new Date(moment().format());
var tLeft = moment(endDate).diff(moment(todayDate));         
element.text(moment.unix(tLeft).format('d:h:mm:ss'));
```

Please suggest